# Understanding Pytorch memory allocation on GPU

Tags: python, memory-management, out-of-memory, pytorch

I have the following code snippet to do complex multiplication in Pytorch

[**Variation 3**](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/eduardo4jesus/3595eef44fef29be722b44e90fee5119/dot-product-out-of-memory-3.ipynb)

```
def complex_mult(x, y):
  a, b = x[:, :, :, :, :, 0], x[:, :, :, :, :, 1]
  c, d = y[:, :, :, :, :, 0], y[:, :, :, :, :, 1]
  out = torch.stack([a*c - b*d, a*d + b*c], dim=-1)
  return out
```

As I was investigating why I am getting `RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory`,
I realized that the memory allocation depending on the number of instruction I explicit give.

I wrote that code in three different ways, the other two as as bellow.

[**Variation 2**](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/eduardo4jesus/9c16d12891d1fe9bd53ec26324438c70/dot-product-out-of-memory-2.ipynb)

```
def complex_mult(x, y):
  a, b = x[:, :, :, :, :, 0], x[:, :, :, :, :, 1]
  c, d = y[:, :, :, :, :, 0], y[:, :, :, :, :, 1]
  real = a*c - b*d
  imag = a*d + b*c
  pair = [real, imag]
  out = torch.stack(pair, dim=-1)
  return out
```

[**Variation 1**](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/eduardo4jesus/ca3248ae86aee5f66e428b7c48b18707/dot-product-out-of-memory.ipynb)

```
def complex_mult(x, y):
  a, b = x[:, :, :, :, :, 0], x[:, :, :, :, :, 1]
  c, d = y[:, :, :, :, :, 0], y[:, :, :, :, :, 1]

  r1 = a*c
  r2 = b*d
  real = r1 - r2

  i1 = a*d
  i2 = b*c
  imag = i1 + i2

  pair = [real, imag]
  out = torch.stack(pair, dim=-1)
  return out
```

From [Variation 1 Gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/eduardo4jesus/ca3248ae86aee5f66e428b7c48b18707/dot-product-out-of-memory.ipynb) , we have:

- All the tensors use `float32`, which is `4 bytes`
- The size of `_x` is `(128, 64, 32, 32, 2)`, thus `64 MB`, `32 MB` each component `(real, imag)`
- Each component multiplication (`a*c`, `b*d`, `a*d` and `b*c`) will have `2048 MB`

  - Which is `64` times the `32 MB` of each component of `x`
  - Subtotal of `8 GB`
- Plus `2 GB`, if consider each `sum` result as storage on its own variable

  - Subtotal of `12GB`
- Stacking `real` and `imag` requires more `4 GB`

  - Total of `16 GB`

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 4.00 GiB (GPU 0; 14.73 GiB total capacity; 12.12 GiB already allocated; 1.82 GiB free; 12.12 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

Intuitively, I then decided to stick with [Variation 3](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/eduardo4jesus/3595eef44fef29be722b44e90fee5119/dot-product-out-of-memory-3.ipynb) by thinking

> - "Without those temporary variable (place) holders, Torch will know that they won't be used again, thus releasing their memory. Thus using only `4 GB` by the end of my execution."

---

But, what I don't understand, and **here is my question**, is

> Why, on [Variation 3](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/eduardo4jesus/3595eef44fef29be722b44e90fee5119/dot-product-out-of-memory-3.ipynb), I still get `CUDA out of memory` after a few calls to that method? The gist show that in the third call it crashes for not having enough memory.

What is even more interesting is that, though one can think

> - "That is because there is already `4 GB` that is allocated with the previous result."

However, given that it was able to execute twice, I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to post the full code. Since variation 3 was able to run twice, the OOM error might be caused by accumulated gradients in some other part of the code.

Comment: The codes are posted as links. Click on `Variation 3`